# can't change My site host location

Tags: my-site

I meet a issue that we have a web application, there are two web zones:
Default zone: `http://webserver20:91`
Internet zone: `http://www.abc.com`

I can't change the my site host location in My Site settings of the User Profile service application. The value of my site host location is `http://webserver20:91/sites/personal`. I want to change it to `http://www.abc.com/sites/personal`, I found that the system always restore it to `http://webserver:91/sites/personal`.

Do you have any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a new Alternate Access Mapping.
Some refs:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/530934/SharePoint-Alternate-Access-Mapping-Configuration

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3s_uY983LXM